# Can't select from a temporary table

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables, postgresql-9.4

I have 3 tables - `T_USER`,`T_PRIVILEGE` and `T_USER_PRIVILEGES`.

`T_USER_PRIVILEGES` is a reference table holding references from `T_USER` rows to `T_PRIVILEGE` rows. I want to delete a row from `T_USER`, for which i need to delete the references from `T_USER_PRIVILEGES` first, and also all referenced rows from `T_PRIVILEGE`.

I want to create a temp table holding all the referenced rows from `T_PRIVILEGE`, then delete all the references from `T_USER_PRIVILEGES`, and finally delete all the rows from `T_PRIVILEGE` that are stored in the temp table.

What I try to do is create a stored procedure that accomplishes it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "SP_DELETE_USER"(userid character varying) RETURNS void AS
$BODY$CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_privilege_ids
(
    privilege_id VARCHAR(100)
);    

SELECT "PRIVILEGE_ID"
INTO temp_privilege_ids
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM "T_USER_PRIVILEGES"
WHERE "USER_ID" = userid) as foo;

DELETE FROM "T_USER_PRIVILEGES"
WHERE "USER_ID" = userid;

DELETE FROM "T_PRIVILEGE"
WHERE "ID" IN
(SELECT privilege_id FROM temp_privilege_ids);$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
ALTER FUNCTION public."SP_DELETE_USER"(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

`userid` is a parameter for the SP.

When I try to create the SP pgAdmin says:

> ```
> relation "temp_privilege_ids" does not exist
> LINE 19: (SELECT privilege_id FROM temp_privilege_ids);$BODY$
> ```

I have searched everywhere for an explanation, but didn't find an answer.
Anyone has an idea?

This is the reference table:

```
CREATE TABLE "T_USER_PRIVILEGES" (
  "USER_ID" character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  "PRIVILEGE_ID" character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_T_USER_PRIVILEGES" PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ID", "PRIVILEGE_ID"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_T_USER_PRIVILEGES_PRIVILEGES" FOREIGN KEY ("PRIVILEGE_ID")
      REFERENCES "T_PRIVILEGE" ("ID") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_T_USER_PRIVILEGES_USER" FOREIGN KEY ("USER_ID")
      REFERENCES "T_USER" ("ID") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE INDEX "FKI_T_USER_PRIVILEGES_PRIVILEGES"
  ON "T_USER_PRIVILEGES" ("PRIVILEGE_ID" COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `select .. into temp_privilege_ids` should be `insert into temp_privilege_ids select ...`. Or better: use just a single `create table ... as select ...`

Comment: The existence of the tables is checked during _compile_ time, and when you create the function, the table does indeed not exist. The compiler doesn't know that the table will exist at runtime.

Comment: Plus: the temporary table is totally useless. This can be done with just two plain delete statements (or: create a FK constraint between the two tables with `on delete cascade`)

Comment: I can't do it without the temporary, since I have a FK and have to delete from the reference table first. Also does it basically mean that i can't use temp tables in SPs?

Comment: Regarding the FK, I have two FKs going out from the reference table into the other two tables, but would DELETE CASCADE work in that case?

Comment: There are various solutions for your problem. Please provide the ***complete*** `CREATE FUNCTION` statement that produced your error. Never just a confusing snippet. The function header is an integral part.

Comment: Sure you can do without the temporary table. You need to delete from `T_PRIVILEGE` first (using a sub-query), then delete from `t_user_privileges`. Unrelated, but: you should really stay away from quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it in the long run.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have edited the post to contain the whole CREATE function. At first I added only the code I wrote in the wizard code editor, the rest is generated automatically by Postgres.

Comment: You write `userid is a parameter for the SP`, but there is no parameter in the updated function definition (which is a *function* BTW, not a stored procedure - there are no actual SP in Postgres).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm new to Postgres, so i tried to uphold the upper-case convention for table names as in SQL Server, but you are probably right and i should just use lower case. Regarding the query, can you please supply an example?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are right. As I couldn't save the function, I just recreated it now and forgot to add it - this is not the reason for the error I get. I edited the code to receive the parameter as well.

Comment: You don't need to (and probably you can't) delete from `t_privilege`. What if there are privileges used by _other_ users than the one you are trying to delete? All you need to do is: `delete from t_user_privileges where user_id = ...; delete from t_user where id = ...;`, see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51097/1  Also: why do you prefix each table name with `T_`? Do you prefix all your classes in your programming language with `C_` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language SQL functions are planned *at once*, so you cannot reference any tables that are not there yet. You could create the temp table by hand to pass the superficial syntax check at creation time and allow the creation of the function, but the function would still fail at execution.

You *could* implement what you are trying with a plpgsql function (applying some of the advice @a_horse_with_no_name already provided in the comments):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SP_DELETE_USER"(_userid varchar) RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_privilege_ids ON COMMIT DROP AS
   SELECT "PRIVILEGE_ID"
   FROM   "T_USER_PRIVILEGES"
   WHERE  "USER_ID" = _userid;

   DELETE FROM "T_USER_PRIVILEGES"
   WHERE "USER_ID" = _userid;

   DELETE FROM "T_PRIVILEGE" t
   USING temp_privilege_ids tmp
   WHERE t."ID" = tmp."PRIVILEGE_ID";
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But that's still needlessly convoluted. Just use a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH del1 AS (
   DELETE FROM "T_USER_PRIVILEGES"
   WHERE  "USER_ID" = _userid  -- provide userid here
   RETURNING "PRIVILEGE_ID"
   )
DELETE FROM "T_PRIVILEGE" t
USING  del1
WHERE  t."ID" = del1."PRIVILEGE_ID";
```

Leaving aside my doubts towards your database design and your naming convention.

---

[According to your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235655/cant-select-from-a-temporary-table/33253565?noredirect=1#comment54309209_33253565), your FK constraint `"FK_T_USER_PRIVILEGES_PRIVILEGES"` seems to be pointing in the **wrong direction**: it's for the case where multiple users can be linked to the same privilege (which would make sense).

If so, drop this constraint and create one on `"T_PRIVILEGE"."ID"` instead:

```
ALTER TABLE "T_PRIVILEGE"
ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_T_PRIVILEGE_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ID")
   REFERENCES "T_USER_PRIVILEGES"("PRIVILEGE_ID") 
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then privileges are deleted *automatically* when you delete rows in `"T_USER_PRIVILEGES"`, due to the `CASCADE` clause.

Still an odd design. "Privileges" are typically something that multiple users can share ...

Comment: The `delete from t_privilege` will fail if a privilege is used by other users as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yup. I doubt the setup makes sense. Just demonstrating the proper techniques. Cant fix the broken design here. I would use different names and data types, too.

Comment: The relation between a user and privileges is one to many, meaning no one else will use the privilege.

Comment: @Elliko: If that's so, then your FK constraint `"FK_T_USER_PRIVILEGES_PRIVILEGES"` is pointing in the wrong direction: it's for the case where multiple users can be linked to the same privilege (which would make sense).

Comment: It does make sense. And then I could simply use DELETE CASCADE. Thanks.